# Conditional remote validation in razor pages using data annotation

Tags: asp.net-core, tabs, razor-pages, remote-validation

I have to validate a field based on another fields input.
If Field A is not empty, then Field B should be filled out.
Currently this form is inside a tab,so when i do the javascript validation it is navigating to the first tab.
Here is my code for Model Class

```
    //--WorkpassType ---//
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select WorkPass Type")]
    [Display(Name = "WorkPass Type"), StringLength(20)]
    public string WorkpassType { get; set; }

    //--Workpass Expiry Date ---//
    //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select WorkPass Expiry Date")]
    [Display(Name = "WorkPass Expiry Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? WorkpassExpiryDate { get; set; }
```

Index.cshtml

```
    <form method="post" id="FormBiodata" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <partial name="_BioData" />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-left:800px;">
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' />
                <input type="submit" id="BtnSubmit" asp-page-handler="InsertBioData" style="display:none;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Javascript Validation

```
     $('#FormBiodata').submit(function () {

        if ($('#DropDownWorkPassType').val()) {
            if ($('#WorkPassExpiryDate').val() == null) {
                $("#SpanWorkPassExpiryDate").html("Please Enter WorkPass Expiry Date");
                $('#myTab li:nth-child(@Model.currentTab) a').tab('show')
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            $("#BtnSubmit").click();
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: After you enter data into the input and lose focus,it will go to the handler which defined in PageRemote attribute.So the data will not be checked when click submit button.You'd better use js rather than remote validation.

Comment: @YiyiYou but when i click submit button, the page reloads to first tab and the error message is not showing with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `e.preventDefault();` in form submit js:

```
 <form method="post" id="FormBiodata" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-page-handler="InsertBioData">
        <partial name="_BioData" />
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10" style="margin-left:800px;">
                <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

js:

```
$('#FormBiodata').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($('#DropDownWorkPassType').val()) {
            if ($('#WorkPassExpiryDate').val() == null) {
                $("#SpanWorkPassExpiryDate").html("Please Enter WorkPass Expiry Date");
                
            }
        }
        else {
            this.submit();
        }
    });
```